# How do I reformat status messages?

Tags: 6, hooks

I'm trying to restyle the status messages block, and I just can't figure out how to do it.  I ought to be able to -- it's just defining a theme function, right? :) -- but it's just not happening for me.  I'm not sure if I'm not defining the function properly, or not registering it properly in hook_theme, or even if I need to register it in hook_theme.  Arggh -- can anybody out there clarify this for me?  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the function you need to hook is:

`themename_status_messages()`

where themenameis your theme's name. You can see the [status message theme docs here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_status_messages/6).

What specifically are you trying to restyle? Most of it can be done with CSS, without introducing a theme hook.

Comment: Thanks to @jonathan and @jimajamma; problem solved. themename_status_messages does indeed work nicely; it was one of the things I had tried unsuccessfully before. The problem -- now solved -- is that, some time ago, I had installed the Messages Alter module.  This gets in the way of themename_status_messages doing its thing; with Messages Alter disabled; all is well.  In any case, my need for this in the first place is so I can add some jquery-based control over the message displays, and a bit more stuff is needed than can be added just w. css.  In any case, thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `theme_status_messages()` all you need to do is create a `phptemplate_status_messages()` or `YOURTHEMENAME_status_messages()` function in the `template.php` file in your theme's directory and do whatever you want to do differently (the original is defined in `includes/theme.inc`).